# Rendering same component twice in different pages in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Pagination from "./components/pagination.js";
import Header from "./components/header.js";
import DataBox from "./components/stats.js"

const imageHeaderIndex = document.getElementById("imageHeaderIndex");
const navBarIndex = document.getElementById("navBarIndex");

const imageHeader = document.getElementById("imageHeader");
const navBar = document.getElementById("navBar");
const dataDiv = document.getElementById("textualContent");

ReactDOM.render(<Header/>, imageHeaderIndex)
ReactDOM.render(<Pagination/>, navBarIndex)

ReactDOM.render(<Header/>, imageHeader)
ReactDOM.render(<Pagination/>, navBar)
ReactDOM.render(<DataBox url="http://localhost:8081/stats/pageInfo" pollInterval={2000}/>, dataDiv);
```

Hello all, I am very new to javascript and react. I have the code above and I was trying to render the same react component twice, but on different pages. 
ids = imageHeaderIndex and navBarIndex belong to index.html, while the rest belong to another page (stats.html)

However, the components are not reflected on stats.html. And I faced the error: Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element. Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the right approach when working with `React`. While you are "thinking in components", the actual app needs structure. One recommendation is Container components, which if need be, can manage state and pass it down. Anyways, why not have one component that you pass into `ReactDOM.render`, something like so

(note: I do not know the structure of the app, this is an example)

// one HTML element with `id="main"`, one React Container called `<App />`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Pagination from "./components/pagination.js";
import Header from "./components/header.js";
import DataBox from "./components/stats.js"

const main = document.getElementById("main");


const App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id="main">
        <Header>
          <Pagination></Pagination>
          <Header>
            <Pagination></Pagination>
          </Header>
        </Header>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App url="http://localhost:8081/stats/pageInfo" pollInterval={2000}/>, main);
```

Ideally, you only have one `ReactDOM.render' function per file.

Comment: Hi, how should I go about doing it if I were to have only one "ReactDOM.render" function per file? @JordanHendrix